# Etherscan.io API call response with "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page."

Tags: etherscan

Trying to make api call like:

```
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x6a21bA9Bdc40D8626FB4352eF0C9adb32DEd3e9c&tag=latest&apikey=blablabla
```

Getting this response with GET and POST methods:
[image]

That wasn't an issue like two days ago... Any ideas? I can get response using web browser like Chrome.

Comment: Ask this Q in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be okay to me (now), I've just tried the URL that you specified and I get the following output:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"2988824706000000000"}
```

I also, independently, followed the API documentation which resulted in the following URL:

```
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xB5920c14c92762FBAbbE04dF87F2DC1E84672369&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

That also works correctly:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"90434356586133208510"}
```

Looks to me like it could just have been a bug that you were unfortunate enough to hit.